# Undefined Opencv References when using Qt + Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, qt4

Hello im basically trying to make an application that shows and Opencv Iplimage converted to QImage in a label, i did a simple example and it worked just fine, but now when i try to integrate that image convertion to another project,i get undefined Opencv functions references like this: undefined reference to `cvQueryFrame'all from the Highgui

Im actually using the same library paths i used when i first tried that image convertion, just that this time its not working. Im quite new with Qt, and i dont know where the problem might be:

```
 #include <qt4/QtGui/QApplication>
 #include "myqtapp.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <opencv/highgui.h>
 #include <opencv/cv.h>

 using namespace std;
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {

QApplication app(argc, argv);
myQtApp *dialog = new myQtApp;
//********************************************************************************************************
QImage myImage; 
QLabel label_5;
IplImage* frame;   
//label_5 = new QLabel(myQtAppDLG); //Not using this Yet
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "garden.bmp" );  
frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
cvCvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2RGB); 
myImage = QImage((unsigned char *)frame->imageDataOrigin,frame->width,frame->height,QImage::Format_RGB888);  
//label_5.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage)); //Not using this Yet
//********************************************************************************************************
dialog->show();  
return app.exec();
```

}

```
 main.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `cvCreateFileCapture'
 main.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `cvQueryFrame'
 main.cpp:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `cvCvtColor'
```

As you see the first thing i try to do is just to use some Opencv Functions like CvQueryFrame, the funny thing is that im using the exact same include paths i used the first time, also linked the exact same dynamic libraries. I've tried different paths and compiler but nothing seems to work, i dont know where the error might be. Im using Linux Ubuntu and Netbeans C++, Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to include the highgui library in your library path. cvCreateFileCapture and cvCvtColor are part of that library.

Comment: Yea thanks, i solved it, the thing was that i already included the library path as i always do, but there was something wrong with the compiler, i had to add the library directly in my project's makefile

Comment: Strange, but it seems now it's not in highgui. I get a "was not declared in this scope" for `cvCvtColor`, and I searched through highgui, there is no mention of `cvCvtColor` in it! A lot of other functions work just fine.

Comment: @vsz: yes, many things changed in the new versions. but, based on the code provided in the question, I believe the question was addressed with opencv 1.x in mind.